# Ruby - looping through an array, appending a hash - odd behaviour

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I'm confused about the way an array is updated when I loop through it.  Here's a made up example that shows the behaviour.

```
people = [{"name"=>"Edward", "age" =>"43", "height"=>"tallish"},
          {"name"=>"Ralph", "age" =>"40", "height"=>"medium heigth"},
          {"name"=>"George", "age" =>"35", "height"=>"very tall"},
          {"name"=>"Mark", "age" =>"25", "height"=>"short"}]
numbers = ["1","3","26"]
new_array = []

numbers.each do |number|
    people.each do |person|
        person["name"] = person["name"] +" "+ number
        new_array << person
    end
end
```

At the end of that new_array is

```
[{"name"=>"Edward 1 3 26", "age"=>"43", "height"=>"tallish"},
{"name"=>"Ralph 1 3 26", "age"=>"40", "height"=>"medium heigth"},
{"name"=>"George 1 3 26", "age"=>"35", "height"=>"very tall"},
{"name"=>"Mark 1 3 26", "age"=>"25", "height"=>"short"},
{"name"=>"Edward 1 3 26", "age"=>"43", "height"=>"tallish"},
{"name"=>"Ralph 1 3 26", "age"=>"40", "height"=>"medium heigth"},
{"name"=>"George 1 3 26", "age"=>"35", "height"=>"very tall"},
{"name"=>"Mark 1 3 26", "age"=>"25", "height"=>"short"},
{"name"=>"Edward 1 3 26", "age"=>"43", "height"=>"tallish"},
{"name"=>"Ralph 1 3 26", "age"=>"40", "height"=>"medium heigth"},
{"name"=>"George 1 3 26", "age"=>"35", "height"=>"very tall"},
{"name"=>"Mark 1 3 26", "age"=>"25", "height"=>"short"}]
```

Each person appears three times, which I what I expected and wanted.  BUT their name is the same each time.  I expected name to be `"Edward 1"` the first time, then `"Edward 1 3"` and finally `"Edward 1 3 26"`

What's going on here?  I thought the loop would append each separate hash onto new_array, rather than 3 all the same.

Comment: What output do you really want? There may be a simple non-iterative solution.

Comment: @Mark Thomas - I really want each hash with the name element changed several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your code a little bit to see the process

```
numbers.each do |number|
    people.each do |person|
        person["name"] = person["name"] +" "+ number
        new_array << person
        puts person["name"]
    end
end
```

You will get this result:

```
Edward 1
...
Edward 1 3
...
Edward 1 3 26
...
```

As you can see the algorithm works almost as you expected. But `person["name"]` is reference to only one object(string), that's why the final result has the last string `Edward 1 3 26`

**EDIT**: To get your what you wanted you should create new object every time

```
numbers.each do |number|
  people.each do |person|
    person["name"] = person["name"] +" "+ number
    new_array << person.dup
  end
end
```

Don't forget reinitialize the people variable because this expression

```
person["name"] = person["name"] +" "+ number
```

modifies the people variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how do I get what I wanted - an array with the different names?

Answer (score 1):

`people.each` is providing you with a reference to each entry in `people`, so when you do `person["name"] =...` you're modifying the original array.

Try this:

```
numbers.each do |number|
    people.each do |person|
        new_person = person.dup
        new_person["name"] << " " + number
        new_array << new_person
    end
end
```

Comment: new_array still ends up the same as before!  I guess now new_person is a reference which gets updated.

Comment: ...huh. I was not expecting that. I'll try to dig a bit further - this really should be possible.

Comment: See megas' answer - you just put the .dup to early

Comment: But his answer will still edit the original `people` array... surely?

Comment: Sorry, my question can't have been clear - I'm not particularly bothered about the original array, but what I get in new_array.